# use file as an array and store objects as variables inside Jenkinsfile

Tags: arraylist, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In `pseudo code` I want to achieve this within `groovy`.

```
file 
a a1 a2 a3
b b1 b2 b3
c c1 c2 c3

file = /path/to/file

    for (line in file) {
        var_1=line1.a
        var_2=line.a2
        var_3=line.a3
    }

echo $var_1
echo $var_2
echo $var_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new File('/path/to/file').withReader("UTF-8"){r->
    def headers=null
    r.eachLine{line, index->
        line = line.split(' ') //one space is a column delimiter
        if(index==1){
            //convert first line to a map - [ column-index : column-name ]
            headers=line.toList().indexed()
        }else{
            //convert line to headers-to-values map to be able to access value by column name
            line = headers.collectEntries{k,v-> [v, line[k]] }
            println line.a
            println line.b
            println line.c
        }
    }
}
```